# Is there a way to have a placeholder when select returns no rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a table, `report_total`, that contains calculated values for some of the `total_types_cd` (codes) but not necessarily all of them.

If there is no corresponding row, I'd like to have a placeholder in the select such that the `renamed total_amt`  (`unitem_cntrib`/`total_contrib`...) has a value of `0` and I always get a return of 8 items even if no values were found.  I thought maybe the `COALESCE` function might work but I have not been able to write a query that was acceptable.

These query results are going into a pdf report and so I want something, even if it is 0.  Right now, no report is getting generated because the select returns no row if **all** the values are not present.  Below is my select statement and the `$P{ReportID}` is input into the report generator.

```
SELECT  unitem_cntrib, total_cntrib, unitem_expnd, total_expnd,
        unitem_pldg, on_hand, tot_loan, unitem_loan
FROM
(select total_amt  from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='UNITEMIZED_PLUS_LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_CNTRB' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  unitem_cntrib,
(select total_amt from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='GRANDTOTAL' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_CNTRB' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  total_cntrib,
(select total_amt from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='UNITEMIZED_PLUS_LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_EXPND' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  unitem_expnd,
(select total_amt from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='GRANDTOTAL' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_EXPND' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  total_expnd,
(select total_amt from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='UNITEMIZED_PLUS_LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_PLEDGE' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  unitem_pldg,
(select total_amt from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_CNTRB_BALANCE' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  on_hand,
(select total_amt  from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_LOAN_PRINCIPAL' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  tot_loan,
(select total_amt  from report_total where calculation_type_cd ='UNITEMIZED_PLUS_LUMPSUM' 
and total_type_cd = 'TOT_LOAN' and report_info_id=$P{ReportID} ) AS  unitem_loan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when calculation_type_cd = 'UNITEMIZED_PLUS_LUMPSUM' 
                 and total_type_cd = 'TOT_CNTRB' 
                then total_amt end) as unitem_cntrib,
       max(case when calculation_type_cd = 'GRANDTOTAL'
                 and total_type_cd = 'TOT_CNTRB' 
                then total_amt end) as total_cntrib,
       . . . 
 from report_total rt
where rt.report_info_id = $P{ReportID};
```